# SAP Crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, ssms-2016

I have department Name  columns as five records:
1.tyre
2.tank
3.wheel
4.paint
5.engine

I need the SQL query When I select all the above mentioned department at the same time to display all the records it should display as  (ALL Departments)

Column Name-DeptName(if i select all the department it should show deptname as All Departments)
Example:
DeptName-All Departments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a multi-value parameter for the user to select departments.

Create and use a formula based on that parameter like this:

```
IF "tyre" in {?Dept}
AND "tank" in {?Dept}
AND "wheel" in {?Dept}
AND "paint" in {?Dept}
AND "engine" in {?Dept}
Then "ALL Dept" ELSE {yourDepartmentDatabaseColumn} ;
```